# Are commented codes removed from compiled binary for iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

New to Swift, couldn't find an answer to this with a reliable source.

I have some commented code, but would like to know if they are removed when compiled/run in Debug/Release, and if this is enforced or can be turned on/off.

If they are indeed removed, what about those instances where I really need them to be inside, e.g. some framework or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Comments are entirely stripped from code during compilation, and there's no way to force the code to somehow get included if still commented out. Can you explain why you might need code that's otherwise commented out to be included in your final product? Why can't you just leave the code uncommented?

Comment: Sorry I should have rephrased 'commented code' to '{code} comments', my bad.

Comment: Ah. In that case, could you add an example to your question which shows off what sort of comment you’d want to include? For one thing, after you compile a framework, how would you want someone to be able to read the comments? (Since they won’t have access to the source code… Unless you are distributing the source, in which case, it shouldn’t matter if the comments are removed after compilation, yeah?)

Comment: Can't think of any examples but sometimes we want to Option + Click on it to show some comments for a function or variable, but if it is a framework or package I guess the source code is not accessible but we would still want to see the documentation. I just came across https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/documenting-a-swift-framework-or-package and based on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-symbol-documentation-in-your-source-files it seems like comments are still entirely removed but if it is DocC 'compatible' comments (except `//`) then it is 'saved'..

Answer (score 2):

If you create inline docs in a swift package, they're available to the consumer. If you provide a [Docc](https://github.com/apple/swift-docc) asset, that will also be available to the consumer.

If you create a binary, that depends on how it's created and distributed.

Unless there is a security concern not to share the source code, I would do a vanilla SwiftPackage with documentation comments.